# Problems streaming audio on Android 6.0.1 with mediaplayer

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

Since I updated my phone, a *Samsung S6*, to *Android 6.0.1*, mediaPlayer have started to behave strange.

I use the `MediaPlayer` to stream *.mp3* audio over *http* and it has earlier worked without any problems.

Since this update almost all audio I stream which is longer than 1:30 will be stopped too early.

**Example:**

```
05-02 20:58:11.031 3119-26787/? V/MediaPlayerService: [1952] getDuration = 377496
05-02 20:58:11.031 15611-15611/com.test.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getDuration: 377496 (msec)
05-02 20:58:11.031 15611-15611/com.test.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 119842 (msec)
05-02 20:58:11.041 15611-15611/com.test.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
05-02 20:58:11.041 15611-15611/com.test.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
05-02 20:58:11.061 3625-4927/? V/BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{d8b120b u0 null qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{436e057 16133:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a11}
05-02 20:58:11.151 3625-4936/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 16021:com.samsung.android.themecenter/1000 (adj 15): DHA:empty #31
05-02 20:58:11.171 3625-4951/? D/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.samsung.android.themecenter, Auto Run ON
05-02 20:58:11.241 3119-16904/? I/NuPlayerDecoder: [audio] saw output EOS
05-02 20:58:11.241 3119-16903/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: onQueueEOS audio finalResult : -1011
05-02 20:58:11.371 3119-16903/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: [audio] notifyEOS() End of Stream, delayUs : 590370
05-02 20:58:11.371 3119-16903/? V/AudioSink: stop
05-02 20:58:11.681 3119-16896/? D/GenericSource: cachedDurationUs = 0.00 secs, eos=1
05-02 20:58:11.961 3119-16893/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: reachedAudioEOS (1)
05-02 20:58:11.961 3119-16893/? V/NuPlayer: reached audio EOS
```

As the log shows, a call to `getDuration()` is made (377496 ms).
Directly after a call to `getCurrentPosition()` is made (119842 ms).

After this `NuPlayer` seems to detect an EOS and the `OnCompletionListener` is performed and the audio is stopped.

Just before I updated to Android 6, this worked without any issues.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on and how this can be prevented?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is getting more weird.
The logic for the onCompletionListener seems to behave correct, I have discovered that the buffering seems to be the issue.

The onBufferingUpdateis getting called as expected but it will never reach to 100%. Instead it stops somewhere on 33-43%.

I'm performing my tests on a WiFi network so the connection should not be the issue.

Testing with Android M 6.0.0 works fine, this only occurs for 6.0.1. 

Quite annoying, has anybody a hint?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes it is, since I need to know if there are any workarounds that can make the buffering to work properly, eg. set some specific member or such.

Comment: Where's the code then?

Comment: any solution? I met same problem, the media player "saw EOS" too early.

Comment: any one got the answer